# Most pythonic way enumerating broken a table?

Tags: python, for-loop, enumeration

I have something like this:

```
for i, item in enumerate(weapons):
    print "%s : %s" % (i, item)
print "#####"
for i, item in enumerate(weapons):
    if item is not 'bananas':
        print "%s : %s"%(i, item)
```

And I get this:

```
0: apples
1: bananas
2: oranges
3: pears
4: coconuts
#####
0: apples
2: oranges
3: pears
4: coconuts
```

But I would like to increase the 'i' only if it's used, creating

```
0: apples
1: oranges
2: pears
3: coconuts
```

What's the most pythonic way of doing this? I was using a predefined variable outside the for-loop and increasing it by 1 every iteration. Like this.

```
i = 0
for item in weapons:
    if item is not 'bananas':
        print "%s : %s"%(i, item)
        i += 1
```

But it seems very ugly.

Comment: First of all why are you using `is` operator here?

Comment: Use Pandas Series http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.html for efficiently performing this.

Comment: Aशwini चhaudhary, because 'is' is more readable than '=='.

Comment: @f.rodrigues Who told you that they are equivalent?

Comment: @f.rodrigues `"foo" == u"foo" -> True` `"foo" is u"foo" -> False`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send filtered items to the `enumerate`:

```
weapons = 'apples', 'bananas', 'oranges', 'pears', 'coconuts',
for i, item in enumerate(item for item in weapons if item != 'bananas'):
    print "%s : %s"%(i, item)
```

output:

```
0 : apples
1 : oranges
2 : pears
3 : coconuts
```

Comment: Thanks, exacly what I was looking for! Python never ceases to amaze me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple items which you don't want to show (based on falsetru's answer):

```
do_not_show = ['bananas', 'oranges']
for i, item in enumerate(itm for itm in weapons if itm not in do_not_show):
    print "%s : %s"%(i, item)
```